# how to send maximum number of udp packets per second

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, udp

i have an application in Visual Studio 2010 for c++
on windows server 2008 r2

pseudo code is as follows

create multicast socket

while ( still data to transmit == true ) {
 sendto ( multicast socket, data )
}

but i can only achieve around 60k msgs/second with this,where each packet is about 50bytes in size.

can anyone advise how to send higher number of messages per second?
im thinking i can try to bind 2 or more NICs and
should i try to use a thread safe message queue and a thread pool, 
where each thread just trys to pull an element off the queue 
and sendto ( multicast socket, data );
?

any ideas here?

Comment: Are you trying to send over multiple gigabit NICs?

Comment: i am currently trying to send over a single 1G NIC

Comment: 60,000/s would seem to be pretty close to the wire limit. How many bytes of data are in each packet?

Comment: each packet is about 50bytes in size; 60k msgs/sec * 50 bytes = 2.8 megabytes/sec. that is nowhere near 1GB.sec limit of the NIC. but it needs to send the full frame every time which is the MTU which is 1500 bytes 60 000 * 1500 bytes = 0.670552254 gigabits/sec which is not terrible, i just want to get near 1.0

Answer (score 0):

the only way to get it any faster is to bypass the network layer, and use raw sockets.

Comment: Can I do that without using kernel bypass like solarflare? or do I need that?

Comment: no kernel bypass is needed, if your using the berkley or windows sockets either one.

Comment: I'm wondering if using multiple sockets in different threads could help... I have the same issue in my application on Windows, sending about 150k packets per second dispatched on 20 different IPs.